# Convert Integers to Dollar Format in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle Database version 12.1.0.2.0. I'm running a query that returns integers that is actually a dollar amount:

```
SELECT value AS "Valuation" FROM estimates;
```

Result:

[image]

Instead, I would like to show:

```
$115,508
$38,150
$92,832
$116,222
```

How can I convert the integers into dollar $ format?

Comment: Number Format Models: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Format-Models.html#GUID-291CA766-0B7D-4336-954A-B8A23036F6ED

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov Please provide example.

Comment: Examples are in SQL language reference, section [Number format models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `TO_CHAR` function:

```
TO_CHAR(SOME_NUMBER, '$999,999,999,999,999')
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bc6e42a337364091e5d625db7fd2e715)

Answer (score 1):

Use to_char with extended parameters `format` and `nlsparam`: [TO_CHAR (number)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html#GUID-00DA076D-2468-41AB-A3AC-CC78DBA0D9CB)
and [Number Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Format-Models.html#GUID-291CA766-0B7D-4336-954A-B8A23036F6ED):

You can specify currency with `NLS_CURRENCY` and "Group symbol" (`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS('dg')`)

```sql
SELECT 
   to_char(
       value
      ,'L999g999'
      ,q'[
          NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'
          NLS_CURRENCY = '$'
      ]') AS "Valuation" 
FROM estimates;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7cc3c36485cc29f7701e251a786552fe)

Results:

```
         Valuation
           $11,234
              $104
          $321,349
            $2,837
```

**NB:** It's not necessary to specify extra NLS parameters if they correctly set on session level! So it will be much more agile and users will be able to use own session settings.

Comment: Regarding your final note: If you have two users, one American and one French, then you do not want them to use their session defaults as $10,000 is not the same as €10,000 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0c182313a414184f17414dac3dc3e250).

Comment: @MT0 It is obvious. Our real applications contain special functions to calculate prices using different current exchange currency rates (different rates: Visa/Mastercard or official national bank's exchange rate, etc)

Comment: It is not obvious because you do not mention it in your answer.

Comment: @MT0 And again read note carefully "they correctly set on session level"

Comment: @MT0 what? It's not obvious for you that $1 != 1€ ?

Comment: Then please [edit] your answer to show how to correctly set on the session level the ability to convert $10,000 into the appropriate currency value for the user's session taking into account the exchange rate. I believe I stated in the first comment that $10,000 is not the same as €10,000 so there is no need to attempt to be so disparagingly patronising.

Comment: Just use ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CURRENCY = '$'; in your DBFiddle if you work with USD only: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5107602702b119f314ba1738393aa741

Comment: "so disparagingly patronising" was your comment and example, which purposely ignored `NLS_CURRENCY` mentioned twice in my answer...

Comment: It was not ignored, as I said at the start of the comment, I was responding to your final line where you state that "NB: It's not necessary to specify extra NLS parameters if they correctly set on session level" - i.e. you are saying that you can remove the third argument from the query and rely on the session settings and I was pointing out that this is dangerous as it risks conflating $1 with €1 when the user changes their `NLS_TERRITORY` setting and a different currency is displayed. ...

Comment: You can argue that "the session settings are not correct" in that case but that does not remove the risk that any user can change their own session settings at any time and so reliance on session settings has risks of misrepresenting the data.

Comment: Your idea is really cool: so all your users have direct access to database, can change session settings and rejoice "hey, I just turned water into wine". Happy end. And all is fine, and 1000 is still 1000...

Comment: And don't forget they are also Time Lords! Cronus!

Answer (score 0):

Can get rid of the left spaces if you really want that:

```
SQL> SELECT ltrim(to_char(value,'$999,999')) AS "Valuation" FROM estimates;

Valuation
---------
$115,508
$38,150
$92,832
$116,222
```

Bobby

Comment: You do not need `LTRIM`. Use the format model `fm$999,999`.